Can I get into trouble for using a DnD monster name for a username?
I had planned on creating a Twitch/YouTube channel. My username on ps4 and other places contains the name of a DnD monster (the bugbear.) Would my channel ever be in danger of action against it from WoTC for using the name?

"Bugbear" meaning "an object of terror" has been an English word since at least 1580, FYI.

I haven't heard from Rowling's lawyers or SE moderators yet regarding my cheesy name. On the other hand, I am not influential or widely known.

For the record, this question was cross-posted from the RPG Stack. As I’ve answered it there, I’ll not repeat myself here—but if anyone from here with relevant expertise wants to comment there, I’d be happy for any corrections anyone cares to offer.

No. You wouldn't be violating the law. Among other reasons, this is because the word "bugbear" like almost all DnD monster names, are drawn from real world myths and didn't belong to the people who used the name in the first place.

And even if the name were original and trademarked, trademarks don't prevent personal use, only uses in commerce, and usually in the same field as the trademark owner. If I wanted to use the username "mswindows", I don't think Microsoft could legally stop me (although if they tried, I probably wouldn't want to spend the money to fight it).

@Barmar I said "Among other reasons", because I can think of three or four reasons it wouldn't violate the law.

@Barmar That also depends on what qualifies as personal use. Playing games on your own time is one thing. Playing games on video services and accepting subscriptions and ad money/sponsorships (as is often the case on Twitch and Youtube) while using an original and trademarked name as your main identity could very well be infringing.

@nitro2k01 The importance of personal use v. commercial use is vastly over estimated by most non-lawyers.
